# Using temporary table in an ADO Recordset

Tags: t-sql, vb6

Please see the code below:

```
rsTitle.Open "CREATE TABLE #TestTable (testtitle varchar(10)) INSERT INTO #TestTable values ('TestTitle') select * from #testtable", objCon.ActiveCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

rsTitle is always closed after the line above is executed.  Why is this? It should return one row.

Comment: Try adding `set nocount on` to the beginning of the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `SET NOCOUNT ON`. Put `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the SQL statement used with ADO, as shown below:

```
Dim adoCn As adoDb.Connection
Dim adoCm As adoDb.Command
Dim rsTitle As adoDb.Recordset

Set adoCn = New adoDb.Connection
...    
Set adoCm = New adoDb.Command
With adoCm
    Set .ActiveConnection = adoCn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #TestTable (testtitle varchar(10)) " & _
                   "INSERT INTO #TestTable(testtitle) values ('TestTitle') " & _
                   "SELECT * FROM #TestTable go"
    .Execute 
End With

Set rsTitle = New adoDb.Recordset
With rsTitle
    Set .ActiveConnection = adoCn
    .Open "SET NOCOUNT ON"
End With
rsTitle.Open adoCm, , , ,
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This worked fore the code in the question.  However it did not resolve the issue with the actual code I had a problerm with.

Answer (score 0):

For that type of mixed DDL+SELECT statement you are better off:

```
Set rstitle = objCon.ActiveCon.Execute("SET NOCOUNT ON; CREATE TABLE #TestTable (testtitle varchar(10)); INSERT #TestTable values ('TestTitle'); select * from #testtable", adCmdText)
```